# Attribute is => 'Maybe[SomeSubtype]' returns Attribute () does not pass type constraint

Tags: perl, moose

I've created subtype `Birth_d` with coercion as shown below, and I'm trying to use it in combination with the built-in `Maybe` type, per [Moose::Manual::Types](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Types).

I'm getting the error `You cannot coerce an attribute (birth_d) unless its type (Maybe[Birth_d]) has a coercion`.  Here's complete test code:

```
package Student;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

use DateTime::Format::MySQL;

class_type 'Birth_d', { class => 'DateTime' };

coerce 'Birth_d',
  from 'Str',
  via { DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_date( $_ ) };

has 'name' => (
  isa => 'Str',
  is => 'ro',
);

has 'birth_d' => (
  isa => 'Maybe[Birth_d]',   # This works:    isa => 'Birth_d'
  coerce => 1,
  is => 'ro',
);


package main;

use Test::More;

my $student = Student->new(
  name => 'Johnnie Appleseed',
  birth_d => '2015-01-01'
  );

is ( $student->birth_d->ymd(), '2015-01-01' );

my $student2 = Student->new(
  name => 'Foo Bar',
  birth_d => undef
  );

is( $student2->birth_d, undef );
```

Replacing `isa => 'Maybe[Birth_d]'` with `isa => 'Birth_d'` works, but is not what is needed. I need to make the birth_d optional, and if not supplied, should be undef.

I should add, I tried using MooseX::Types to tuck this Birth_d type away in a separate place, but found its cavalier use of barewords a bit unorthodox, so I slowly backed away. I'm open to reconsidering it, if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: I am not sure why you need the Maybe at all.
The attribute is not required, so if it isn't supplied, it will not be set.
You could add a predicate => 'has_birthdate' to be able to check whether it was set.
Please note that the way you coerce, once something IS supplied, the parser method will die anyway, so the maybe would not help.
This is perfectly in line with how Moose works generally: supply invalid input, and it dies with an appropriate error.

Comment: @bytepusher, good point, I've added 2nd test case to illustrate what I seek.

Comment: I understand what Maybe does. I am saying you could change that to `is $student->has_birthdate, undef` and just not set it in new. I do not see the value in keeping the undef ;)

Comment: There's a subtle but important difference. $student->has_birth_d tells us whether birth_d has been entered. is ($student->birth_d, undef) tells us birth_d has been entered as 'unknown'.

Comment: Regarding MooseX::Types - that bareword unorthodoxy is an advantage - it lets you get [compile time checking](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html#strict-subs)

Comment: What about `Birth_d|Undef`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find it more useful to not have a Maybe[Birth_d] type, but simply declare the attribute with the Birth_d type, and no "required" set.

That way, if a valid String is passed in, it will be accepted, an invalid String will lead to an error, and nothing just does not need to be passed in.

However, you can coerce to a maybe type:

```
subtype 'MaybeBirth_d',
    as maybe_type(class_type('DateTime'));

coerce 'MaybeBirth_d',
    from 'Str',
    via { DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_date( $_ ) };

has 'birth_d' => (
    isa => 'MaybeBirth_d',
    coerce => 1,
    is => 'ro',
);
```

I just do not see the value of being able to pass in undef for a birthdate - how is that better than not setting it?

I would also like to suggest using `no Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;` and `no Moose;` at the end of your package, or `namespace::autoclean;` at the beginning, as well as `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;` at the end of your Student class.

Comment: See my 3rd comment above, I think we posted at the same time.

Comment: And birthdate not set is " I know it, but I ain't tellin' " ?

Answer (score 5):

Moose [does not do any chaining of coercions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod#Deep-coercion), in other words you have to tell it explicitly how to convert to a `Maybe[Birth_d]`.

You can do this by reusing the existing coercion to `Birth_d`:

```
package Student;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

use DateTime::Format::MySQL;

# save the Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint object
# you can also get it with find_type_constraint('Birth_d')
my $birth_d = class_type 'Birth_d', { class => 'DateTime' };

coerce 'Birth_d',
  from 'Str',
   via { DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_date( $_ ) };

subtype 'MaybeBirth_d',
     as 'Maybe[Birth_d]';

coerce 'Maybe[Birth_d]',
  from 'Str|Undef',
   via { $birth_d->coerce($_) };

has 'name' => (
  isa => 'Str',
  is => 'ro',
);

has 'birth_d' => (
  isa => 'Maybe[Birth_d]',
  coerce => 1,
  is => 'ro',
  predicate => 'has_birth_d', # as per your comment
);


package main;

use Test::More;

my $student = Student->new(
  name => 'Johnnie Appleseed',
  birth_d => '2015-01-01'
);

is ( $student->birth_d->ymd(), '2015-01-01' );

my $student2 = Student->new(
  name => 'Foo Bar',
  birth_d => undef
);

is( $student2->birth_d, undef );

ok( $student2->has_birth_d );

done_testing;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it explains the key point I was missing -- that Moose won't do so-called "deep coercion". So while Maybe[SomeSubtype] is ok on its own, it won't work with coercion.